# How to check if a file only contains 6 tabbed delimited columns in python

Tags: python

I am trying to check if a file contains only 6 tabs with as many rows but been pretty stuck. here is what I got although i think it is not doing what I want because this is for start of a line?

```
with open (myfile, 'r') as f:
    line_lengths = [len(line) - len(line.lstrip()) for line in f]
    if len(line_lengths) !=6:
        print "file is not tab delimited"
    else:
        print " file is ok. Proceed"
```

I have a file with 6 tab delimited columns but it is giving me file is not tab delimited.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean 6 columns that are tab delimited, or 6 tab characters?

Comment: Like I mentioned, the file contains 6 tab separated columns with hundreds of rows. Wonder why -1. it is not a duplicate because I have not seen any question like that. Trying to learn please

Comment: 6 tab delimited columns would have 5 tab characters per line. Don't sweat one downvote; some people are trigger happy with downvotes.

Comment: Also, I think you're confused about what `lstrip` does. It strips leading whitespace, it doesn't remove tabs throughout the string.

Comment: I appreciate so like Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams responded, so no difference between line counts and column counts?

Comment: You want to check for both 6 rows and 6 columns?

Comment: No just the columns. The answer I got is good. I just wanted to know if its line.count for my current question then what will it be for rows?

Answer (score 1):

Six tab-delimited columns means five tab characters.

```
line.count('\t') == 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted will create a list of the difference between the original line length and the length of the line stripped of leading whitespace, then count the result. This effectively gives you the line count, which you then compare with the desired number of columns.

If what you want to do is verify all lines have 6 tab-delimited columns, use Ignacio's answer with `all`:

```
NUMBER_COLUMNS = 6
with open (myfile, 'r') as f:
    if all((line.count('\t') == NUMBER_COLUMNS-1 for line in f)):
        print "file is not tab delimited"
    else:
        print " file is ok. Proceed"
```